# Problem while create custom UIView with , Xib error found nil with @IBOutlet

Tags: ios, swift

got error found nil at line "contentLabel.text = content"

turn on / off commonInit

```
class SuccessfulView: UIView{

  @IBOutlet weak var contentLabel: UILabel!

  convenience init(content:String ,frame: CGRect){
    self.init(frame:frame)
    contentLabel.text = content

  }

  required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)



  }
  override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame) // calls designated initializer

  }



  func commonInit(){
    Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("SuccessfulFooterContentView", owner: self, options: nil)
    addSubview(contentLabel)
  }

}
```

create subclass of UIView which has xib

Comment: How are you creating the instance of this view?  In order for the outlet to be bound you would need to be instantiating the instance within a view controller that is itself being loaded from a NIB or storyboard scene and you wouldn't access it from your convenience init

Comment: The outlets haven't been initialized yet on init(). You should set contentLabel.text on awakeFromNib.

Comment: Did you connect your label to storyboard ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is if you call `init(frame:)` of a `UIView`, it won't initialized by your *interface builder* (storyboard/Xib).

So you should initialize your view by a Xib. Just like-

```swift
var content: String = ""

static public func instance(content: String, frame: CGRect) -> SuccessfulView? {
    let view = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("SuccessfulFooterContentView", owner: self, options: nil) as? SuccessfulView
    view?.frame = frame
    // and save your content
    view?.content = content
    return view
}
```

Then set your content in the awakeFromNib func

```swift
override func awakeFromNib() {
   super.awakeFromNib()
   contentLabel.text = content
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are saying

```
Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("SuccessfulFooterContentView", owner: self, options: nil)
```

in the belief that this will cause this variable

```
@IBOutlet weak var contentLabel: UILabel!
```

to be set. But it won't be unless the File's Owner in the nib is set to the SuccessfulView class and the `contentLabel` outlet hooked up.

Answer (score 0):

In my solution fix this problem by connect outlet view root in **File'Owner**.

First check you is connect outlet of view is done.
Second check you is connect content view in file owner

same below this image.

[image]

```
 @IBOutlet public weak var mContentView: UIView!
override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.setupView()
    }
    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        self.setupView()
    }
    
    func setupView() {
        Bundle(for: Onboard.self).loadNibNamed("OnboardStepperView", owner: self, options: nil)
        self.addSubview(self.mContentView)
        self.mContentView.frame = self.bounds
        self.mContentView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleHeight,.flexibleWidth]
    }
```